# Why do I get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with this?

Tags: java, arrays

Hey there pretty new to Java I have a CSV file that I am scanning line by line (I am assuming) and printing out the details formatted. I keep getting a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 what could I be doing wrong?
Here is the CSV file contents.

```
1,Mazda CX-9,7,Automatic,Premium,150

2,VW Golf,5,Automatic,Standard,59

3,Toyota Corolla,5,Automatic,Premium,55

4,VW Tiguan,7,Automatic,Premium,110

5,Ford Falcon,5,Manual,Standard,60
```

```
    String fileName = "CarList.CSV";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        carsAvailableCount++;
        String line = input.nextLine();
        int lenght = line.length();
        String fields[] = line.split(",");
        String carNo = fields[0];
        String carName = fields[1];
        String seats = fields[2];
        String transmission = fields[3];
        String carType = fields[4];
        String rate = fields[5];

        System.out.format("%-9s%-9s%-9s%-9s%-9s%-9s\n", carNo, carName, seats, transmission, carType, rate);

    }
```

Comment: empty first/last line? Use a debugger

Comment: I would strongly recommend using a debugger - it will make everything much clearer. As a matter of style, I'd also recommend using `String[] fields` instead of `String fields[]` - the latter is really only valid in Java for compatibility with older languages, and is generally discouraged. (Personally I think it was a mistake to allow it, but...)

Comment: @Ron Quick question, did you initially tag this with Javascript and then edit it out right after posting? I"m curious whether there's a Stack Exchange bug or something else's going on, see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396497

Comment: @ CertainPerformance No I tagged Java and Arrays I believe

Answer (score -2):

Figured out the problem haha, my CSV file had empty lines below my last entry. Cheers everyone.